# Need UL and LI to replace Javascript menu

Tags: javascript, html

Using Jquery context menu on right click. By this way I am calling a dropdown menu. Instead of this, I need to use HTML using UL and LI.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" class="showcase">
    $(function() {
        $.contextMenu({
           selector: '.projects-dropdown', 
 
            items: {
                "iteml": {name: "iteml"},
                "item2": {name: "item2"},
  "item3": {name: "item3"},
                "item4": {name: "item4"},
    }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So that I want to give a separate link for each menu item.

Comment: And what have you tried?  Making a pure HTML unordered list is very, very simple and the slightest of effort to find an example would give you thousands.  Is there an actual problem here, or are you just asking us to make it for you?

Comment: One issue was there. Having treeview menu inside the table. rightclick on icon in <td>, then dropdown menu should appear. table having overflow : auto so dropdown is getting behind the table. I used Jquery context menu. But client asking that dropdown menu should come in ul and li

Answer (score 0):

And if you still not find here is basic example :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

just copy and paste it =)